# How to import new project into perforce

Tags: java, automation, perforce

In my perforce depot already have one java project and I am trying to add one more new eclipse java project in same depot which is in my local machine. I google it and tried myself to add new project but i am fearing to add it because if will do any mistakes it can affect my existing project.
Can any one suggest me step by step how to add new project into perforce so it will not affect my existing project.

Thanks.

Comment: Put it into a different directory. You can have multiple directories in the same Perforce depot.

Answer (score 1):

As far as Perforce itself is concerned, adding one set of files into Perforce does not have any effect on other existing files.  From the command line you can just do:

```
p4 add ...     (or specify a directory; "..." is the current directory)
p4 submit
```